# How to sort the Oracle db query result based on a condition?

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

In my **Activities** table I have a **duration** column. The duration can be in months like 1m, 4m, 8m.. etc or it can be in years like 2y, 5y, 9y etc. In my query i want to write an orderby in the ascending order based on the duration. Following is my query.

SELECT ACTIVITY,DURATION FROM ACTIVITIES

ORDER BY 2

The traditional order by is returning the result as 1m,2y,4m,5y,8m,9y. Instead I want the result as 1m,4m,8m,2y,5y,9y.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

general and specific to your case:

```
select blablabla from activities
order by decode(substr(col, len(col)-1, 1), 'm', 1, 'y', 12, 0)*
to_number(substr(col, 1, len(col)-1)
```

or (direct)

```
select blablabla from activities
order by decode(col, '1m', 1, '4m', 2, '8m', 3, '2y', 4, '5y', 5, '9y', 6, 7)
```

or (positional)

```
select blablabla from activities
order by instr(col, '1m,4m,8m,2y,5y,9y')
```

or (general, but simple)

```
select blablabla from activities
order by substr(col, len(col)-1, 1), substr(col, 1, len(col)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting your values to months or days most likely so you are comparing "apples to apples".  You should be able to do this fairly easily in the Select statement by multiplying your months or years out (unfortunately you would have to settle on a month equal to 30/31/x days in this scenario as well as a year of 365 days since leap would not be handled) since you do not have a specific date available).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SUBSTR` to check the unit, and just cast the rest to an integer (adjusting for the unit) to do the sorting;

```
SELECT ACTIVITY,DURATION FROM ACTIVITIES
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN SUBSTR(DURATION, -1, 1) = 'y' 
       THEN CAST(SUBSTR(DURATION, 1, LENGTH(DURATION)-1) AS INT) * 12
       ELSE CAST(SUBSTR(DURATION, 1, LENGTH(DURATION)-1) AS INT)
       END;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0c36/8).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT activity, duration
FROM (SELECT activity,
               duration,
               substr(duration, length(duration)) unit,
               to_number(substr(duration, 1, length(duration) - 1)) VALUE
          FROM activities)
ORDER BY unit, VALUE;
```